# How do I get my SQL results to appear in one table instead of two within PHP/HTML

Tags: php, html, html-table

I have a PDO connection to a database that returns any results for an item number that is searched. It currently returns each instance in its own table but i would like to see all instances in one table. Here is my code.

```
if (count($resultssample) > 0) {
        echo "<br>";
        echo "Number in the business: ".count($resultssample)."<br>";
        echo "<br>";
        foreach ($resultssample as $r) {
            echo "<table>";
            echo "<thead>";
            echo  "<tr>";
            echo    "<th>site name</th>";
            echo    "<th>location name</th>";
            echo    "<th>creation time</th>";
            echo    "<th>creation date</th>";
            echo    "<th>damage status</th>";
            echo    "<th>colour</th>";
            echo    "<th>inventory status</th>";
            echo    "<th>notes</th>";
            echo  "</tr>";
            echo "</thead>";
            echo "<tbody>";
            echo  "<tr>";
            echo    "<td>". $r['site_name'] ."</td>";
            echo    "<td>". $r['location_name'] ."</td>";
            echo    "<td>". $r['CreationTime'] ."</td>";
            echo    "<td>". $r['CreationDate'] ."</td>";
            echo    "<td>" . $r['damage_status'] . "</td>";
            echo    "<td>" . $r['colour'] . "</td>";
            echo    "<td>" . $r['inventory_status'] . "</td>";
            echo    "<td>" . $r['Notes'] . "</td>";
            echo  "</tr>";
            echo "</tbody>";
            echo "</table>";
        }
      } else {
        echo "No results found";
      }
```

How can this be achieved I cant currently get my head around it.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Move `<table>` tags outside `foreach` loop

Comment: inside your `foreach` you should only have the `tr` and `td` rows. The `table, thead, tr, th, /tr, /thead, tbody` should all go before your loop, and `/tbody, /table` should go after the loop.

Comment: Ahh I see thank-you so much. its so simple but not something I would have seen. It makes sense now looking at it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All you have to do is move table header out of the foreach loop:

```
if (count($resultssample) > 0) {
        echo "<br>";
        echo "Number in the business: ".count($resultssample)."<br>";
        echo "<br>";
    
        echo "<table>";
        echo "<thead>";
        echo  "<tr>";
        echo    "<th>site name</th>";
        echo    "<th>location name</th>";
        echo    "<th>creation time</th>";
        echo    "<th>creation date</th>";
        echo    "<th>damage status</th>";
        echo    "<th>colour</th>";
        echo    "<th>inventory status</th>";
        echo    "<th>notes</th>";
        echo  "</tr>";
        echo "</thead>";
        echo "<tbody>";     
    
        foreach ($resultssample as $r) {
    
            echo  "<tr>";
            echo    "<td>". $r['site_name'] ."</td>";
            echo    "<td>". $r['location_name'] ."</td>";
            echo    "<td>". $r['CreationTime'] ."</td>";
            echo    "<td>". $r['CreationDate'] ."</td>";
            echo    "<td>" . $r['damage_status'] . "</td>";
            echo    "<td>" . $r['colour'] . "</td>";
            echo    "<td>" . $r['inventory_status'] . "</td>";
            echo    "<td>" . $r['Notes'] . "</td>";
            echo  "</tr>";
            
    
        }
        
        echo "</tbody>";
        echo "</table>";
            
    } else {
        echo "No results found";
    }
```